# Generate NBINGARCH in R

Tags: r, time-series, negative-binomial-distribution, garch

Could someone help me show or suggest how to generate data from negative binomial Garch (NBINGARCH(1,1)) model and how to write find the parameters using MLE ?
Thank you so much